# for loop and condition when I click

Tags: php, sql, loops, for-loop

I create a binary tree. I have a first question and when I click on 'yes', I want to see a second question which is left etc. But here, I see directly the last item.

When I click, I want to display a next item of my db like this:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
    if(isset($_POST['yes'])){
        $select = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM node where id=:id');
        $select->bindParam(':id', $current_id_left);
        $select->execute();
        $nodes = $select->fetch();

        $current_id_left = $nodes->id_left_node_children;
        $current_id_right = $nodes->id_right_node_children;
        $current_question = $nodes->questions;
    }
```

It works but the loop gives me the last item. Before the last item, I have a second item which is not displayed.

How can I display items one by one?

Comment: you need to loop over the results of your query, not just ->fetch() the first one.

Comment: id field of DB is unique?

Answer (score 3):

Use limit in mysql query. For first record use below query.

```
SELECT * FROM node where id=$id LIMIT 0,1
```

For next question change LIMIT 1,1, LIMIT 2,1 so an so..

So update your start value of LIMIT by passing that value from next button thats it.